# How do I get access to the features Vaadin claims to have

Tags: maven, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I'm trying to use Vaadin to make a table (technically a grid).

Someone saw a demo on vaadin's website, and basically just wants that recreated and tweaked: https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/grid/features

I downloaded the starter project from https://vaadin.com/start/v10-simple-ui, and I was able to tack my table onto their demo app easily.

However, the features on their demo aren't available to me.  Specifically, column.setHidable(true) isn't something I can call, because the Vaadin library lacks that method, even though it's in their demo.

I'm wondering if that's because the demo lied about vaadin's capabilities, or because I haven't downloaded the right part of a modular application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sampler is based in Vaadin 8, which is the current stable version. Vaadin 10 is currently in beta, and it has a different API. You may download some of the Vaadin 8 starters, such as [v8-project-base](https://vaadin.com/start/v8-project-base), or take a look at the [Vaadin 10 demo](https://vaadin.com/flow/demo).